# Is it possible to present an embedded file as a filename?

Tags: go, embed, filenames

I use a [function](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/melbahja/goph@v1.2.1#Key) that requires a **filename as a parameter (of type `string`)**. It works fine when providing the filename.

I would like to [embed this file](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) in my binary. I can then have the contents as `[]byte` or `string` but that's not useful. I can also fave it as `embed.FS` but my understanding is that this is an abstraction that can be used by some functions only.

What I would need is the ability to **present this embedded file as a filename** (a `string`) that would then be used by the underlying function to open the (embedded) file.

Is this possible?

Comment: @colm.anseo: well yes, my question was about how to directly access the filenames of these embedded files (which apparently is not possible)

Comment: If the real path of the embedded file can be relied on at runtime, then there's no need for embed.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco: yes there is: to have the file within the binary.

Comment: My point was that the purpose of embedding the file, is that you can't necessarily rely on that file to exist in the local file system once deployed. In that case, getting the file path if the embedded file isn't really useful, because again, we've already said that you can't rely on the file being there. The root if your issue seems to come from poor library design, where it forces you to pass the path of a file-on-disk. If you want to use some in-memory data instead if a file, you could write to a temp file and then pass the path of that.

Answer (score 3):

Filename that Key accept as string argument is only abstraction on [ioutil.ReadFile](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil#ReadFile), see [auth.go](https://github.com/melbahja/goph/blob/bce96423006ac91b959986e1a493a9d1936d103d/auth.go#L64)

What you can do is implement ssh.Auth yourself, here is small example.

```
package main

import (
    _ "embed"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/melbahja/goph"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

//go:embed id_rsa
var privateKey []byte

func main() {
    auth, err := Auth(privateKey, []byte("foobar"))

    fmt.Println(auth, err)
}

func Auth(privateKey, pass []byte) (goph.Auth, error) {
    signer, err := Singer(privateKey, pass)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return goph.Auth{
        ssh.PublicKeys(signer),
    }, nil
}

func Singer(privateKey, pass []byte) (ssh.Signer, error) {
    if len(pass) != 0 {
        return ssh.ParsePrivateKeyWithPassphrase(privateKey, pass)
    }
    return ssh.ParsePrivateKey(privateKey)
}
```

Comment: Thanks fo the full answer & rewrite - but I would be interested in the general answer as well (for other cases)

Comment: short answer - **no it's not possible**. You passing location of your `privatekey` file on disk, `ioutil.Readfile` read it. You can't pass `fs` into this process, so you can read from emebeded fs.